# V8 - SetAccesor can't add to a existing template

Tags: c++, v8

I have the following code :

```
        while (bson_iter_next(&iter))
        {
            const char* key = bson_iter_key(&iter);
            if (!_paths.count(key)) 
            {
                _template->SetAccessor(
                    String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, key),
                    &BSONObject::getter,
                    &BSONObject::setter
                );
            }
        }

    Local<Object> obj = _template->NewInstance();
```

I build a object with all fields in a document BSON. I have a list of documents and they all go through this code. I realized that if the first have not fields which others have they won't be define. I explain :

```
BSON 1 : {foo: 3}
BSON 2 : {foo: 2, boo: 4}
```

When I will use my getter in JS he will show me :

```
BSON 1 : {foo: 3}
BSON 2 : {foo: 2}
```

**How I can add this field's accessor ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the same `ObjectTemplate` for objects with different numbers of properties.

I can think of two alternatives; which one is better depends on the rest of your app:

- create a fresh `Object` every time, and call `SetAccessor` (or `CreateDataProperty`?) directly on that `Object`. No `ObjectTemplate` required.
- use `SetHandler` on the `ObjectTemplate` to install a single handler that intercepts *all* property queries.

Comment: How I can handle all properties with `setHandler` because my getter take only the first property. Have you an example of a implementation of `setHandler` ?
I juste add a `v8::NamedPropertyHandlerConfiguration` with only `getter` and `setter` field defined with my old functions.

Comment: All my fields have undefined value.